# Vuex + vue not reactive when using dictionary as state object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-reactivity

I need to use dictionary as one of my store variables, but It's not reactive like array, what is the best practice to solve this?
I've created minimal example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-store-forked-ko3md?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to add new reactive props, instead of using direct assignment, you should use the `Vue.set()` method:

```
  ADD_ITEM(state, { key, value }) {
    Vue.set(state.dict, key, value)
  }
```

For a more in dept understanding of Vue reactivity you should read the official docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Thank you so much! 
Also, I'm wondering can I delete the key from the dictionary using this aproach?

Comment: Of course, you can use `Vue.delete(object, key)`